# How to dump Neo4j data ignoring transction and checkpoint files?

Tags: neo4j, backup

I was using Neo4j 5.1 and then used `sudo apt upgrade` when downloading other tools. This command upgraded my Neo4j to 5.2, but for unknown reasons Neo4j stopped working after the upgrade. I tried to backup and copy it, but all failed. I have a lot of data in my database, can anyone help me...?

Here are error prints. Is there any way to dump the DB without checking checkpoint or transaction file?
[image]

[image]